# Disconect models signals in test mode

Tags: django, django-testing, django-signals, django-tests

Is there any way to disconect models signals in test mode Django 1.11 ?

Or maybe a way to create an object without ORM to prevent dispaching signal from the `post_save` method ?

setup test code

```
def setUp(self):
   #some code
   with patch(post_save):
       self.instance = Instance.objects.create(fields)
```

error : `AttributeError: 'ModelSignal' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These signals shouldn't really be mocked, but if you really need to do it, this should work:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_method(self):
    with patch('django.db.models.signals.post_save.send'):
        MyObject.objects.create()
```

Comment: received error `AttributeError: 'ModelSignal' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`